# Convert C++ Syntax to Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c, callback, pjsip

My background experience is C/C++/C#.

I am using a C++ library in an xcode project (to be specific the library is PJSIP). To use the library i have to wire couple of callbacks to my code like this:

### SipTest.m

```
#include < pjsua-lib/pjsua.h >

static void on_reg_state(pjsua_acc_id acc_id)
{
    // Do work
} 

static void Init()
{
   // pjsua_config and psjua_config_default are  defined in the header file from pjsip
    pjsua_config cfg;            
    psjua_config_default(&cfg);  

    cfg.cb.on_regstate = &on_reg_state;
 }
```

---

I want to switch this C++ sytnax to Objective C

so I did:

```
 +(void) on_reg_state:(pjsua_acc_id) acc_id
 {
    // Do work
 } 

 +(void) Init
 {
    pjsua_config cfg;            
    psjua_config_default(&cfg);  

    cfg.cb.on_regstate = &on_reg_state; // ***** this is causing compile error
                                        // I tried [CLASS NAME on_reg_state] and i get   runtime error
 }
```

I tried to search for delegate in Objective C but i could not find an a similar case where the callback is already implemented in C++ and you want to use it with Objective-C syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there's absolutely no need to convert anything at all. It is perfectly fine to call C++ libraries from Objective-C.

Secondly, whats causing the compiler error is that you're trying to stick a method in a place where there should be a function pointer. You can't make a function pointer out of an Objective-C method using the `&` Operator. Simply keep your `on_reg_state()` function and use it as you did before, that's how you do callbacks in Apple's C-based frameworks, too (which you'll need as soon as you move beyond what the high-level Objective-C APIs provide).

And thirdly, your `+ (void)Init` method seems a bit strange. I would strongly discourage you to write a method called `Init` (capitalized). If you intend to write an initializer, it should be `- (id)init`, i.e. lowercase and returning `id`. And don't forget to call the designated initializer of its superclass, check its return value, assign it to self, and return it at the end of the `init` method (see *Implementing an Initializer* in [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html) if you're not familiar with that). And if your method is not an initializer, use a different name, e.g. `- (void)createConfig`.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you'd want to use selectors.

```
+(void) on_reg_state:(pjsua_acc_id) acc_id
 {
    // Do work
 } 

 +(void) Init
 {
    pjsua_config cfg;            
    psjua_config_default(&cfg);  

    cfg.cb.on_regstate_selector = @selector(on_reg_state:);
    cfg.cb.target = self; //Self here is the class object in your 'Init' method, which is poorly named.
    //Use this like [cfg.cb.target performSelector:cfg.cb.on_regstate_selector withObject:...etc]

 }
```

Comment: I do not have 'on_regstate_selector' and 'cb.target' in cfg?

I agree about Init naming.

Comment: The idea was you'd have to add one. Target+selector is the common paradigm.